# Правка драйвера Kyocera Universal Driver

Tags: печать, драйвер

Добрый день коллеги.
Проблема такая: есть несколько принтеров Kyocera (серия Taskalfa). Есть централизованная система печати MyQ. есть периодически печатающиеся pdf-файлы, которые при использовании Universal драйвера в spooler'e из (к примеру) 7мб pdf-файла в итоге превращают в 160-200 мб. При использовании же драйвера под конкретную модель принтера документ спулится до 40-50мб, что приемлемо. 
Можно ли, что-то сделать с Universal-драйвером, чтобы он не спулил до таких размеров документы ?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что-то сделать программно? Есть на него открытые коды?

Comment: Нет, не программно. Все возможные настройки я уже ковырял. Как я понял, в случае с Universal-драйвером он в спулер подгружает все указанные там модели и драйвера, в отличие от драйвера на конкретную модель